# Generic method in a class which returns same object

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

I have a class and I want to add a generic method to that class which returns a same object every time it calls. But method parameter can be different objects. No matter what the parameter is but the method should always returns the same object type.

The purpose of creating this method is I'm suppose to call an API and I need to send JSon serialized object to that. Every time I call the API, it will create a new customer in their service. API service has only one customer type object. But in my application I have two types of objects (ex: Student, Teacher) API doesn't care whether I'm sending a Student object or Teacher object. Both these objects are a customer in API perspective.

So when ever I call the API I need to create common customer object to pass to the API. But I have two objects in my app and I want to write a method which accept both Student and Teacher objects, but returns a customer object.

Is this possible with generics? Or any other way to make this simple and efficient?

Please see the sample code below.

```
 public static Customer CreateCustomer<T>(T data)
 {
    var customer = new Customer()
    {
        CustomerNo = 1,
        CustomerName = "Test",

        CustomerContact = new CustomerContact()
        {
            CustomerContactName = "Test",
            CustomerContactEmail = "test@test.com",
            CustomerContactPhone = "011111111"
        },
        PrimaryAddress = new CustomerAddress()
        {
            Street = "Hill street",
            ZipCode = "16962",
            City = "New york",
            Country = "USA"
        },
        BillingAddress = new CustomerAddress()
        {
            Street = "Hill street",
            ZipCode = "16962",
            City = "New york",
            Country = "USA"
        }
    };
    return customer;
}

public class Teacher 
{
    public long TeacherID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Subject Subjects { get; set; }

    public string Email{ get; set; }

    public string ContactNO{ get; set; }

    public Address PrimaryAddress { get; set; }

    public Address SecondaryAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Student 
{
    public long StudentID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Email{ get; set; }

    public string ContactNO{ get; set; }

    public Address PrimaryAddress { get; set; }

    public Address SecondaryAddress { get; set; }

    public string Grade { get; set; }

    public int Level { get; set; }
}
```

**T data** can be a Student or a Teacher. I want to replace hard coded values from this **data** object. Is it possible?

Comment: show the Student and Teacher class please

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI I have added them. Please check. Those are sample classes anyway

Comment: Can't you go with dynamic?

Comment: Why generics? what about create 2 different methods, `CreateCustomer (Teacher tch)` and CreateCustomer(Student stud)`? if Teacher and Studend share a common base class (which seems reasonable), you can refactor your code so both CreateCustomer method call a third Method `CreateCustomerFromBaseClass`, and handle the remaining fields in each of the two main methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all write your generic class that look like

```
public class CustomerService<T> where T : class
    {    
        public static Customer CreateCustomer(T data)
        {
            Customer customer = new Customer();

            if (typeof(T) == typeof(Student))  //We just check here is data comes from api is of type Student
            {
                Student student = (Student)(object)data; //then cast this data to Student

                customer = new Customer()
                {
                    CustomerNo = student.StudentID, // Convert.ToInt32(student.StudentID),
                    CustomerName = student.FirstName,

                    //Assign all your remaining customer properties with desired values
                    CustomerContact = new CustomerContact()
                    {
                        CustomerContactName = "Test",
                        CustomerContactEmail = "test@test.com",
                        CustomerContactPhone = "011111111"
                    },
                    PrimaryAddress = new CustomerAddress()
                    {
                        Street = "Hill street",
                        ZipCode = "16962",
                        City = "New york",
                        Country = "USA"
                    },
                    BillingAddress = new CustomerAddress()
                    {
                        Street = "Hill street",
                        ZipCode = "16962",
                        City = "New york",
                        Country = "USA"
                    }
                };
            }

            if (typeof(T) == typeof(Teacher))  //We just check here is data comes from api is of type Teacher
            {
                Teacher teacher = (Teacher)(object)data; //then cast this data to Teacher 

                customer = new Customer()
                {
                    CustomerNo =  teacher.TeacherID,  // Convert.ToInt32(teacher.TeacherID),
                    CustomerName = teacher.FirstName,

                    //Assign all your remaining customer properties with desired values
                    CustomerContact = new CustomerContact()
                    {
                        CustomerContactName = "Test",
                        CustomerContactEmail = "test@test.com",
                        CustomerContactPhone = "011111111"
                    },
                    PrimaryAddress = new CustomerAddress()
                    {
                        Street = "Hill street",
                        ZipCode = "16962",
                        City = "New york",
                        Country = "USA"
                    },
                    BillingAddress = new CustomerAddress()
                    {
                        Street = "Hill street",
                        ZipCode = "16962",
                        City = "New york",
                        Country = "USA"
                    }
                };
            }


            return customer;
        }


    }
```

You may use if-if or if-else-if in above method as your need.

Thne call your CreateCustomer generic method from your api controller action like

The **Student** data or **Teacher** data comes from your front end

```
 [HttpPost]
 //public IHttpActionResult GetCustomer([HttpPost]Teacher teacher)
 public IHttpActionResult GetCustomer()
    {
        Teacher teacher = new Teacher { TeacherID = 12, FirstName = "Vijay" };  //this teacher data comes from front end or from caller of this api
        Customer customer1 = CustomerService<Teacher>.CreateCustomer(teacher);            

        return Ok(customer1);
    }
```

**OR**

```
 [HttpPost]
 //public IHttpActionResult GetCustomer([HttpPost]Student student)
 public IHttpActionResult GetCustomer()
    {           
        Student student = new Student { StudentID = 11, FirstName = "Kunal" };  //this student data comes from front end or from caller of this api
        Customer customer2 = CustomerService<Student>.CreateCustomer(student);

        return Ok(customer2);
    }
```

**Result**

**Teacher as a Customer:**

[image]

**Student as a Customer:**

[image]

Comment: @user2837480, I added solution as your need, check once may it help you, If it helps then accept it :)

Comment: Thank you. I just did the changes as you mentioned but in different way. I just followed @Nick 's answer and his comments below.  Anyway thanks for the answer. It was what i expected.

Comment: yes @Nick and my declaration both are same but in different way. glad to hear you have get rid from your problem :)

Comment: Explanation for my downvote: for your solution, you need to test the type T used and make some `if typeof T == ...` this is usually code smell (more than code smell in this case IMHO). I would go with a different approach, see my comment on OP question

Comment: @Gian Paolo , i didn't get u what you said?

Comment: @Gian Paolo, in question he need generic method not as you said in your comment, we have to give solution to user that those want bcoz we didn't know actual implementation environment of user. we have to provide solution as user want. please vote up

Comment: If user want to actually go through by using two different api, one for `student` and one for `teacher` then he doesn't require to post a question here,  he really want a generic method so that why he post a question.

Answer (score 2):

If both a `Teacher` and `Student` could be made into a `Customer` and those 2 classes share the same data in order to become a `Customer`, it would be better to extract those properties into either a base class or an interface.

For example:

```
public class Person
{
}

public class Student : Person
{
}

public class Teacher : Person
{
}

public static Customer CreateCustomer(Person data)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but you need provide more info about T, and change return type:

```
public T Create<T>(T data) where T : class
{
    return new someType() as T;
}
```

Comment: How can I add T values into my customer object? Can I simply do as data.Name etc?

Comment: you can't add values to T. T it's just generic object class. you can get type of data and cast them to equals type.

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit Teacher and Student from the Customer class.
Now the Customer has to contain the common Information of both classes

```
abstract class Customer {...}
class Teacher : Customer {...}
class Student : Customer {...}
```

then you can treat Teacher and Student as Customer.

```
Customer c1 = new Student();
Customer c2 = new Teacher();

Api.Call(c1);
Api.Call(c2);
```

And the Api.Call should look like this:

```
// in Api class

public void Call(Customer c)
{
  //call the Api
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use if interface or a base class which should have all the properties that Customer class has. Additional properties can be placed in the derived classes. Then your method will require base class or interface.

Since you have mentioned that you will be calling API and post this JSON, you might also want to take a look at `JsonPropertyAttribute` from NewtonSoft (assuming you are using that). That way you do not even need to create a `Customer` object. You can simply decorate your classes to be serialized in the JSON format you want. HTH